# How can I mock .NET code that refers to a private object instance?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, stream, mocking

I have the following code I'm trying to write a unit test for:

```
// Grab all of the content.
var rawContent = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var fileInfo in response.Files)
{
    using (var stream = fileInfo.VirtualFile.Open())
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            rawContent.Append(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I have mocked the Stream instance that `Open()` returns. That's easy. The stream object is also a `MemoryStream`, btw.

But I'm not sure how to setup the `ReadToEnd()` .. to return some string content I have. This is because the `StreamReader` instance is private to this method.

I thought of providing a Property which can be set.

eg.

```
public string AStreamReader { get; set; }
```

then doing this ..

```
// Grab all of the content.
var rawContent = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var fileInfo in response.Files)
{
    using (var stream = fileInfo.VirtualFile.Open())
    {
        using (var streamReader = AStreamReader ?? new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            rawContent.Append(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

and then just passing a mock `StreamReader` through the `AStreamReader` property.

But I don't really want to do this. I feel that I'm leaking some internal logic, unnecessarily, and only for mocking! A real user will never set that, so that feels like a really dirty thing to do.

Comment: Can't you just put the data you want to return in the memory stream that you mocked?

Comment: @JohnKoerner exactly. `StreamReader.ReadToEnd` calls `.Read` on the underlying stream. If you're able to mock the stream, mock `Read`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something but if you are able to mock the input `Stream`, why do you need to mock the `StreamReader`?

Does the following not work for you?

```
    private string ReadFromResponseFiles(Stream[] inputs)
    {
        var rawContent = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var stream in inputs)
        {
            using (stream)
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    rawContent.Append(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }

        return rawContent.ToString();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_read_files()
    {
        var file1 = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Foo"));
        var file2 = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Bar"));

        var result = ReadFromResponseFiles(new[] { file1, file2 });
        Assert.AreEqual("FooBar", result);

        file1.Dispose();
        file2.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: So simple! how did I not see that :(

Answer (score 0):

Set the modifier as protected, and subclass it. It's how we do with most of our tests, in such cases as this.

Comment: I'm not advocating this approach but would it not be better to mark it as `internal` and use the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` giving your test project internal access.

Comment: It's a more proper way to do it, but more hassle if you have a lot assemblies.